# Ansible nested for loop with dynamic key lookup

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible, jinja2

```
ansible [core 2.11.5] 
  python version = 3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 05:25:02) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)]
  jinja version = 3.0.2
  libyaml = True
```

I am writing an Ansible playbook with the purpose of querying a list of EC2 instances and deregistering from Target Groups. Some nodes are registered to both NLB target groups and ALB target groups, so the playbook should be able to determine how to deregister accordingly based on the target group.

Assume I have the following data:

```
# instances_dict contains instance data from ec2_instance_info module
# target_group_dict is a dict as such:
# assume that vars type and deploy_env are known

service_nodes:
  node_one:
    target_group_names:
      - "{{ type }}-{{ deploy_env }}-tcp"
      - "{{ type }}-{{ deploy_env }}-http"
  node_two:
    target_group_names:
      - "{{ type }}-{{ deploy_env }}-tcp"
      - "{{ type }}-{{ deploy_env }}-http"
```

The general python-ish psuedocode equivalent of what I am trying to do is:

```
for instance in instances_dict['instances']: 
  for tg in service_nodes[instance.Name]['target_group_names']:
    if 'tcp' in tg.Name:
      tg.deregister(instance.private_ip)
    if 'http' in tg.Name:
      tg.deregister(instance.instance_id)
```

I am having trouble figuring out if it is possible to use Ansible's various looping features to nest for loops as such. It seems you can loop through known dictionaries or known lists at once, but having a dynamic key lookup based on iterating through another dictionary seems tricky. Has anyone tried to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of experimenting I wasn't able to get this to work in the way that I wanted with raw Ansible.  Perhaps there's still a way.

I ended up solving this problem by invoking the playbook within a Bash for-loop that iterates over a list of the known node names.

Bash script:

```
SERVICES=(
  'node1'
  'node2'
)

for SERVICE_TYPE in "${SERVICES[@]}"; do
  ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml \
  ansible-playbook teardown.yml \
  --extra-vars \
  "service_type=$SERVICE_TYPE \
  etc..."
done
```

Test playbook:

```
# assume the above service_nodes dict from question above

tasks:
    - name: Gather information about any instance with Name including {{ uuid }}
      ec2_instance_info:
        region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
        filters:
          "tag:Name": "{{ type }}-{{ deploy_env }}-{{ service_type }}-{{ uuid }}"
          instance-state-name: [ "running"]
      register: running_node

    - name: Print target groups and types
      debug:
        msg: "Removing {{ running_node.instances[0].instance_id if 'webhttp' in item else running_node.instances[0].private_ip_address }} from {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ service_nodes[service_type]['target_group_names'] }}"
```

Snippet of output showing results:

```
TASK [Print target groups and types] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 11 February 2022  14:34:48 -0500 (0:00:01.775)       0:00:01.824 ******* 
ok: [localhost] => (item=node-sandbox-webhttp) => 
  msg: Removing i-xxxxxxxxxxx from node-sandbox-webhttp
ok: [localhost] => (item=node-sandbox-webtcp) => 
  msg: Removing 10.227.1.217 from node-sandbox-webtcp
```

This makes the output a bit more visually cumbersome but for now I think it'll do the trick.